# Odd behavior with Static Site hosted in Azure Blob Storage using Custom Domain with CDN

Tags: dns, azure-storage, cdn, static-site, azure-cdn

I recently went through the process of building a static website and hosting it on Azure Blob Storage and configuring a custom domain name and https with CDN. I followed all the steps on learn.microsoft.com and configured the DNS in Azure, using Premium Verizon CDN. Everything seems to be working, but I am seeing some odd url behavior

- https://website.com - Page cannot be reached
- http://website.com -
  Site works but QS not passing (/route content has url of base)
- https://www.website.com - Perfect experience
- http://www.website.com -
  Account being accessed does not support http

I have some Custom Rules configured for the CDN, so I assume they may need some tweaking.

Redirecting to Https

[image]

Keeping Paths

[image]

I know the name of my cdn is there, not that concerned. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you get any help on this or any ways you solved it? I have the exact same issue.

Answer (score 3):

Try following this article: https://www.itexperience.net/2019/04/20/the-account-being-accessed-does-not-support-http-with-blob-sas-url-in-azure/

1. Go to your Storage Account (top level) in Azure
2. Go to Settings – Configuration
3. Set “Secure transfer required” to “Disabled“
4. Click Save
5. Retry to access the URL. The file can now be accessed.